# What is the relationship between rejection region and power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I am learning the concept of power of a hypothesis test. 
The text I am following have the following notation...

> Let Θ0 and Θ1 be disjoint subsets of Θ. 
>   Consider the two hypotheses 
>   H0: θ ∈ Θ0
>   H1: θ ∈ Θ1

So if I have test
H0:mu = .52 
H1: mu != 52

then $\theta_0={52}$ and $\theta_1=R - \{52\}$.

The definition of power is $ \inf_{\theta \in \theta_1}  P_{\theta}(reject \  H0)$.

Wouldnt the power always be .5 in the normal case (i.e. moving the blue distribution such that it centres at 52) since Theta1 is pretty much the entire real line?

Here is a plot I made myself...probably theta1 and power are wrong, but what would be the correct theta1 and power?

[image]

Comment: Power is usually defined for a specific alternative; so power at $\theta=\theta_1$ is $P_{\theta_1}(\text{ reject }H_0)$.

Comment: The power depends on the size of the test.  For instance, with a test size of $\alpha=0.05,$ the power in your setting is just $0.05,$ not $0.50.$

Comment: @whuber thats the part I am missing. By definition, power = inf P(rejecting h0 $\theta \in \theta_1$). But my theta1 = R - {52}. Is it right to say that when we take theta=52 (as a limit point), Power = P(rejecting h0 $\theta = 52$) = 0.05?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The crux of the matter is that the definition of power you quote is a limited one: it appears intended for the case where there is a binary choice between $H_0$ and $H_1,$ whereas in the case you posit $H_1$ can be usefully considered as a nested set of alternatives parameterized by $\mu:$ as $\mu$ grows further from $52,$ the alternative becomes less and less likely. From this point of view, power is not a mere number: it is a *function* of the true $\mu$ that increases with $|\mu-52|.$